# Expected value of MGIG distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, random-matrices

I'm currently dealing with a Gibbs sampler of the multivariate generalized inverse Gaussian distribution (MGIG). In order to check the correctness of the sampler, I'd like to know the expected value of this distribution. I read a couple of papers involving the MGIG but none provides the expectation.

Or, better, I'd like to know what is the characteristic function of the MGIG, or the moments generating function.

Comment: Hmm... I will rather check the expectation of the determinant because it is easy to get it. But it involves a matrix Bessel function...

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer.

Let $z \in \mathbb{R}^d$, let $A$ a positive definite $d\times d$ matrix, let $b > 0$, and let $q > (d-1)/2$. Define $p = q + (1-d)/2$ and $H = zz^{t}$. The following is claimed in the paper *"A Bayesian approach for clustering skewed data using
mixtures of multivariate normal-inverse Gaussian distributions"* by Yang & al.

Let $x \sim GIG(-p, z^tAz, b)$ (generalized inverse Gaussian) and $W \sim \mathcal{W}_d(q,A)$ (Wishart) be independant. Then ${(xH + W)}^{-1}$ has the $MGIG(-q, bH, A)$ distribution.

So one has the expectation of *the inverse* of $MGIG(-q, bH, A)$. This is $\mathbb{E(x)}H + \mathbb{E}(W)$, and these two expectations are known.

Now I believe I saw somewhere that this inverse is also $MGIG$. I'll edit this answer if I retrieve the statement of this fact. ***Edit:*** indeed; it is $MGIG(q, A, bH)$.

This is a very partial answer because $bH$ is of rank one and $-q < (1-d)/2 \leqslant 0$.